iOS Keychain data for SDKs
We have a SDK in which we use keychain to store some data. The customers who integrate our SDK in their app are able to delete our data by using SecItemDelete on kSecClass.
Is their any way we can protect the SDK's data from getting delete by the host app or use something only accessible to SDK only ?
Thanks
Not able to find any solution

No. Your framework is part of the app and running in the app sandbox. It is not running in its own sandbox.
